# Change charges group on released items

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2012

I would like to change the charges group on several items via a query, the charges group is part of the Purchase tab.

So I opened the table InventItemPurchSetup, but I can't find the reference to the charges group.

What is the reference from the released product to the charges group (located underneath the purchase tab)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In table InventTableModule filter by

```
ModuleType == Purchase order and
ItemId == "YourItemId"
```

In InventTableModule.MarkupGroupId is your charges group

Best Regards,
Kristian